# CORS not working with jQuery and Java

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, spring-integration

I am a bit stuck trying to make a call to my Java RESTFUL API with jQuery.

Debugging I have found both OPTIONS and GET method are called but when GET method finishes in the server, json is not retrieved and an error raises in the broswer.

**OPTIONS REQUEST**

```
OPTIONS /PTGServices/ptgapi/v1/clients/1/ngos HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:8181
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, cache-control, x-custom-1, x-custom-2, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8181/jquerysample/local/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

**OPTIONS RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 204 Sin Contenido
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8181
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Cache-control,Content-Type,Origin,X-requested-with,X-custom-1,X-custom-2,WithCredentials
Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2014 14:49:25 GMT
```

**GET REQUEST**

```
Accept:*/*
Authorization:Basic dXNlcjp1c2Vy
Cache-Control:no-cache
Origin:http://localhost:8181
Referer:http://localhost:8181/jquerysample/local/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
X-custom-1:value1
X-custom-2:value2
```

In Chrome, this GET request shows an orange warning indicating : 'CAUTION: provisional headers are shown' and there are no GET response

In Firefox, there are no warning but the response is empty too.

After some researching, I found this post indicating both responses (OPTIONS and GET) must have the Allow-Control headers, so I put it but still not work...

http://kodemaniak.de/2010/07/cross-domain-ajax-with-restlet-and-jquery/

Some idea?

Thanks!

**Update 1:**

I have found it can be an Spring Integration "issue", since when I retrieve Access-Allow-* headers, it is being mapping into "X-Access-Allow-*"

Comment: Please show all GET response headers sent by your server according to a proxy.

Comment: I have updated my question because I think I have figure out the problem.

Comment: Antonio, you should configure `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` with `userDefinedHeaderPrefix = null` or empty String. By default it is really `X-`

Comment: Thanks! At this moment I have found this post http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/93167-http-outbound-gateway-and-custom-http-headers indicating this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antonio, you should configure `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` with `userDefinedHeaderPrefix = null` or empty `String`. By default it is really `X-`.

The JIRA ticket on the matter: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-1722

Comment: Hello, Antonio! It would be better to finish this question somehow. We are going to reconsider the `X-` bahavior, BTW: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3903